# Jpanel graphic not moving inside runnable

Tags: java, jpanel, paint, runnable

Any ideas why my oval is not moving to the right? I have a game loop but somehow the circle stays where it appears, instead of moving by 2pixels to the right every cycle.
The strange thing is that it enters the loop before actually painting. But then the graphics object show up(at a fixed position).

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static int WIDTH = 1024;
    public static int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    private Thread t1;
    boolean running;
    private int FPS = 60;
    private long optimalTime = 1000 / FPS;
    private int heroX = 200;
    private int heroY = 200;


    public void addNotify(){
        Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        running = true;
        t1 = new Thread(this);
        t1.start();
    }



    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillOval(heroX, heroY, 50, 50);
        g2.dispose();
    }


    public void run() {
        long startTime;
        long passedTime;
        long waitTime;
        while (running){
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Runs");
            update();
            draw();
            repaint();
            passedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            waitTime = optimalTime - passedTime / 1000000;
            try {
                if (waitTime <= 0){
                    waitTime = 2;
                }
                Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }



    private void draw() {


    }



    private void update() {

        heroX += 2;

    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you *still* don't understand how threading and swing work. Here's the link *again* http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: please, read the linked tutorial :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of trying to use threads. If you need to do something time consuming in the background, use [SwingWorkers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). It is possible to use your own threading with swing should you really need to (you need a twisted user case to need to do that), but do not try to do that until you have a good grasp of threads *and* the way to use them with swing.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int DELAY = 1000 / 60;
    private final Timer timer;
    // ...

    private int heroX = 200;
    private int heroY = 200;

    public GamePanel() {
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                update();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        // ...
    }

    // No need to make this public
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // Overriding is cleaner than using set*Size(). Search old questions to see why
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
         timer.start();
    }

    public void stopAnimation() {
         timer.stop();
    }

    // Remove addNotify() and run()
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think you want to drive me to the fact that swing event must be called from within the edt. Then I suppose that I must not use paintComponent but a graphic object from inside the run method. I'm just starting with java and believe me, I'm finding colliding informations. But I'll persist.

Comment: @GiuseppeTonello it is possible to use threads with swing, but all access to the components must be done in the EDT. The easiest way to use threads is SwingWorkers, but for simple code threads are unnecessary. A timer, like in the code above, can drive animations just fine. For drawing in swing, you really must use `paintComponent()` - `getGraphics()` simply will not work correctly.

Comment: As I noticed from this video, you can. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3BuJcKoljU&list=PL-2t7SM0vDffoasICG7X_6SObAW9L7hph

Comment: @GiuseppeTonello that may work if you are lucky, but it's an extremely bad idea. The Graphics is not guaranteed to stay constant, for instance (if you use any other swing functionality, and if you do not, there's no point in doing it in swing. Using BufferStrategy to do the double buffering is generally better than rolling one's own with BufferedImage). BTW, watching videos to see code is annoying.

Comment: @GiuseppeTonello anyway, if you're following the guy's tutorial, you should follow it exactly. Trying to mix bits from there and some from SO is not going to work until you understand how it works. Stick to one source and check what you are doing differently if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

After reading and testing, I just wanted to do this. It works as intended, even if paintComponent is outside the EDT.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static int WIDTH = 1024;
    public static int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    private int cordX = WIDTH / 2;
    private Thread t1;
    private boolean running = true;

    public void addNotify() {
       super.addNotify();
       Dimension size = new Dimension (WIDTH, HEIGHT);
       setPreferredSize(size);
       t1 = new Thread(this);
       t1.start();
     }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(cordX, HEIGHT /2 , 20, 20);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            cordX += 2;
            repaint();
            try {
                    Thread.sleep(17);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }  
}
```